# Volume element $\mathrm{d}^4k =\mathrm{d}k^0 \,|\mathbf{k}|^2\,\mathrm{d}|\mathbf{k}| \,\mathrm{d}(\cos\theta) \,\mathrm{d}\phi$ in Minkowski space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wick-rotation, special-relativity

Suppose we have an integral

$$\int \mathrm{d}^4k \,\ f(k)$$
we want to evaluate and that we're in Minkowski space with some metric $(+,-,-,-)$.

Is it true that: $$\mathrm{d}^4k = \mathrm{d}k^0\ \mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{k} = \mathrm{d}k^0 \,\,\,\,|\mathbf{k}|^2\,\mathrm{d}|\mathbf{k}| \,\,\mathrm{d}(\cos\theta) \,\mathrm{d}\phi$$

just like in ordinary space?

If not, what are the differences between this and an Euclidean integral in (say) 4 dimensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is.

The [volume form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_form#Riemannian_volume_form) on any (pseudo-)Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ of dimension $n$, where $g$ is the metric, is given in local coordinates $(x^1, \dots, x^n)$
$$
  \sqrt{|\det (g_{\mu\nu})|}dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n
$$
where $\det(g_{\mu\nu})$ is the determinant of the metric in these coordinates.  In cartesian coordinates, the determinant of the Euclidean metric is $+1$ why the determinant of the Minkowski metric is $-1$.  However, the absolute value in the square root factor of the volume form kills the sign difference, so the volume forms are the same.

**NOTE.** The notational convention in physics is
$$
  d^n x = dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n
$$
See, for example, Carroll's *Spacetime and Geometry* eq. 2.95.  So, the answer to your question is really "yes" due to notational convention, but then this begs the question "Why would one use $d^nx$ as the volume form for both Minkowski space and Euclidean space?" whose answer is given abave.

Comment: @PlaneWaves Sorry the answer is kind of abstract.  You might find it helpful to read the link I included on the term "volume form" that talks about volume forms on manifolds.  Also, I added a note that might clear things up a little bit.